# (where) should a timeout for pub-sub be set, Redis or nginx? Or should i use a heartbeat

Tags: nginx, flask, redis, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events

I am having a flask server using Server-Side-Events through redis. Originally Nginx had a timeout for the sse connection, but if nothing gets sent in that time period the connection would timeout, so for that reason i have it temporary disabled.

After some googling i still cant find a concrete answer, where its best set, if it even should be set. I have also seen the use of a heartbeat (sending messages automatically before timeout) but unsure which one is the "correct way of doing it"